# Как заменить что то между символами <@ и > в js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

У меня есть строка, например: <@935569145217552414> как дела? . Мне нужно заменить всё что находится между <@ и >, однако если между ними находится цифра 2, заменять не нужно, например:

```
Строка 1 ( до редактирования ): <@935569145217552414> как дела?
Строка 1 ( после редактирования ): как дела?

Строка 2 ( до редактирования ): <@2> как дела?
Строка 2 ( после редактирования ): <@2> как дела?
```

Comment: могут ли быть внутри <@...> быть символы <, >, @, и вообще любые кроме цифр?

Comment: `<@(?!2>).+?>` https://regex101.com/r/bbFBFm/1

Comment: могут быть только цифры